# Compare rows and columns in same file

Tags: bash

I am looking to understand how can I run a new file from existing one after did some changes.
Example in text document:

name1 Viktor

name1 Kiril

name2 Angel

So my question is, how to combine on new file looking like that:

name1 Viktor,Kiril

name2 Angel

Or at least to print, for example

on name1 - you have 2

on name2 - you have 1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `awk` to map your first column as a key and concatenate the values.

```
cat name_file.txt | awk '{ if(!arr[$1]){ arr[$1]=$2 }else{ arr[$1]=arr[$1]","$2 } }END{ for(i in arr){ print i" "arr[i] } }'`

name1 Viktor,Kiril
name2 Angel
```

`Awk` will process each line using the first column as a 'key' and append the value (second column) onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i got:

```
cat name_file.txt | sort |cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -c | awk {print "on", $2, "you have", $1}'
```

output:

```
on name1 you have 2
on name2 you have 1
```

or

```
cat name_file.txt | sort | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -c
```

output :

```
2 name1
1 name2
```

Comment: Thanks guys I am going to test it :)